# Rails doesn't create route for "controller#new" action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get a weird behavior when trying to do a super easy task:
adding

```
 resources :something do 
   ...
 end
```

to the `routes.rb` generates all routes except `#new`.

when trying to browse 'localhost:3001/somethings/new' it handled by `#show` action.

I'm using rails 5.1.4 version. Any ideas?

[image]

======== UPDATE ========
I added `s` and still have the same problem: Here is the full code example and the result:

```
 namespace :api do
    namespace :webapp do
      resources :user do
        resources :documents
      end
    end
  end
```

[image]

I was able to make it work when added:

`resources :documents , only: [:show, :index, :update, :edit, :new, :create]`

Comment: How does the code block look like that you didn't paste into your question (the `...` part)?

Comment: It seems to be missing `edit` and `new` action

Comment: Try to restart the server, on the URL it should `something` instead of `somethings`

Comment: I suggest you to read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default because you are not following rails standards. You either use singular `resource :something` which does not generate the `index` or `resources :somethings` also I am wondering if this resource could trigger some `pluralization` issue

Comment: No, it's not `pluralization` issue because the same code is working on my hand, I have tested this & seems to be it's working perfectly @FabrizioBertoglio

Comment: @fool-dev but still it is meant to be `resources :somethings`

Comment: Have you defined an API-Only app ?

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Absolutely right ! `resource :something` -> single, `resources :somethings` -> multiple

Comment: @SimonFranzen Yes it's API only app

Comment: @IlyaLibin there are no `new` and `edit` actions in an API-only app. Those apps are meant to display the form for creating/editing a resource, but obviously that is not needed in an API.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio  I have updated the questions with some checks.

Comment: @AlessandroDesantis - Hmmm not so obvious actually, what If I want to prefetch some data for the `new` form. In my case, I redirect a user to `new` form with query string params like that `?images[]=23&images[]=32` so he starts a new document with two images from database on it.
But it good to know, thanks!

Comment: ok  @IlyaLibin but I notice you keep using `resources :user` intead of `users`